# Passing a method with an undefined parameter type to another method

Tags: c#

```
public A SetA(B b) {
    return null;
}

public C SetC(D d) {
    return null;
}

public void ReceiveSet(Func<object, object> func) {

}

public void Main() {
    ReceiveSet(SetA);
    ReceiveSet(SetC);
}
```

It is necessary that the ReceiveSet method can receive the method as a parameter, while previously it is not known which input and output parameter the received method has. In code sample higher, compiler complains that he can't cast parameter to "<"object, object">". And offer to define parameter explicitly as Func "<"B,A">" but this is not exactly what I need. It is can be possible to do as I describe? And if yes, so how can I do it?

Comment: is there a reason you are not using generics? This seems like a slamdunk generics case.

Comment: What does the `ReceiveSet` function actually do? The compiler complains because if it just allowed this, then you could call `func(new E())` or something similar which neither `SetA` nor `SetC` would allow.

Comment: You could make the calls by passing in a lambda that calls the method instead of passing in the method group. `ReceiveSet((a) => SetA(a as B));` and `ReceiveSet((a) => SetC(a as D));`.

Comment: But really this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Not exactly, this is not full code, idea to write unique method, that works different due to income parameters.

Comment: Your idea would violate the S and the O principles of SOLID (single responsibility & open-closed principle).

Comment: @Igor ,probably you are correct

Comment: @dymanoid ,no because A && C, B && D have same behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) to create a `ReceiveSet` which doesn't expect a `Func<object, object>` object, but instead a `Func<T, U>` object, where `T` and `U` can be specified via generic parameters. Then the argument you try to use will fit:

```
public void ReceiveSet<T,U>(Func<T, U> func) {
}
```

You can use this method as follow:

```
ReceiveSet<B, A>(SetA);
ReceiveSet<D, C>(SetC);
```

*(adjust for static/non-static use of course)*

In the first call it expect a `Func<B,A>` object/reference, which your `SetA` method is. In the second call it expect now a `Func<D,C>` object/reference, which your `SetC` method is.